# How to show $\Im\{z\cot(z)\}$ is not $0$ in the first quadrant?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that $\Im\{z\cos(z)/\sin(z)\}$ is non-zero in the open first quadrant of the complex plane, $\Im z > 0$, $\Re z > 0$, but somehow I cannot seem to show it directly. I think I must be missing something obvious. Does anyone know a simple way to see this?

Comment: You know this but you can't show it "directly"? How does your indirect proof go?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : This comes out of Sturm-Liouville Theory, where one considers the function
$$
          \eta_{\lambda}(x)=\cos(\sqrt{\lambda} x)-m(\lambda)\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}},\;\;\; 0 \le x \le 1, \;\;\Im\lambda \ne 0.
$$
The function $m(\lambda)=\sqrt{\lambda}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda})/\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})$ is chosen so that $\eta_{\lambda}(1)=0$. Then you can show
$$
               \int_{0}^{1}|\eta_{\lambda}(x)|^{2}dx=\pm\frac{\Im m(\lambda)}{\Im\lambda}.
$$
(I can't remember if it's plus or minus on the right.) For this case, it seems there must be a direct way.

Comment: Oh. Sure enough I'd agree that's an "indirect" argument. Have you tried just grinding it out? Using the traditional $\Im(z/w)=\Im(z\overline w/|w|^2)=(\Im z\overline w)/|w|^2$ and so on?

Comment: No luck trying identities. I gave up.

Comment: Yeah. Just cranking it out doesn't work quite as simply as I expected...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Maybe this is the only reasonable way to prove such a thing, but it sure seems strange. You get a nice representation using Herglotz' theorem that results in a classical sum expansion of $\cot$ from just knowing the residues. You can, of course get it from the sum expansion, but that's worse than the indirect method I mentioned above!